# loading png in uiimageview crashes app xcode

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, png

I make an image with photoshop in png format. when i try to use in my project in UIImageView and run the app, it crashes just after the launch screen. when i remove the png, the app works great. why it is happening.. here is the link of png.
I want to give frosted glass effect on uisearchbar background. How can I if this image not work?

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparrentSearchBar"];
```

[Download Png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20824532/TransparrentSearchBar@2x.png)

Comment: Got it the size are toooo high... corrected

Answer (score 0):

maybe try with imageNamed:@"TransparrentSearchBar.png"

Answer (score 0):

1) if your imageView is global then you have to it @synthesize Like:(Otherwise sometimes it crash )

.h file

```
   UIImageView *imageView;

   @property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

.m file

```
    @synthesize imageView;
```

and release in dealloc method.

2)imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TransparrentSearchBar.png"];